# New to Twilio - Why can't I see any option for messaging service despite having an active number?

Tags: twilio, messaging, twilio-programmable-chat

Been working on an assistant for a dining booking system, planned out all the logic for SMS and have just bought 1 of the UK phone numbers through Twilio.

Following the tutorials it states to go into the messaging service; however when I look on my console I have no option for messaging, so I'm currently unable to integrate the phone number & flow with one another.

Now I do have a trial account, and wondered if this was the possible cause or am I completely missing something else altogether that's required?

[image: Image shown on Twilio tutorial]
This is the image that's posted on the Twilio SMS tutorial

[image: vs what I see]

Verses what I can see from my perspective.

Now I did explore through all the options and I did find an messaging option under Flex but I wondered is this what I'm looking for, but then I noticed there wasn't any mention of WhatsApp sender under the flex option.

So currently I am at a loss as to what I need to do next in order to start getting things off the ground.

Answer (score 1):

Two options...Login to the Twilio Console (https://console.twilio.com)

Option 1 - Click the plus next to Explore Products, then click the Pin to sidebar icon to the right of Messaging. This will add it to the sidebar menu. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

---

Option 2 - Type "Messaging" into the Search box in the upper right and then click on the Messaging Service choice. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much was wondering what I was missing, and seems I was missing an entire section altogether.